# Sistema de aba em jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou montando um sistema de abas, ele esta funcionado perfeitamente, porém quando abro ele em um celular ele fica tudo bagunçado. Queria deixar ele igual ao do Android, quando tiver muitas abas ele cria uma barra de rolagem.

Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tab-content').each(function (i) {
        var tabTitle = $(this).data('tab-title');
        var current = $(this).hasClass('current') ? "current" : "";
        var newTab = $('<li class="tab-link"></li>');
        newTab.html(tabTitle)
                .addClass(current)
                .attr('data-tab', $(this).attr('id'));
        $('ul.tabs').append(newTab);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.tabs li', function () {
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

        // Verifica se a aba atualiza a página
        if (tab_id === "tab-0") {
            location.reload();
        }

        $('.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
    });
});
```

```css
.tabs-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul.tabs {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
}
ul.tabs li {
    background: none;
    color: #616161;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul.tabs li.current {
    color: #484848;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #F65314;
}
.tab-content {
    display: none;
    padding: 15px;
}
.tab-content.current {
    display: block;
}
.tab-link:hover {
    color: #FBBC05;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs-container w30">
                <ul class="tabs"></ul>

                <!-- Abas 1 -->
                <div id="tab-1" data-tab-title="ABA 1" class="tab-content current">
                    Texto 1
                </div>

                <!-- Abas 2 -->
                <div id="tab-2" data-tab-title="ABA 2" class="tab-content">
                    Texto 2
                </div>

                <!-- Abas 3 -->
                <div id="tab-3" data-tab-title="ABA 3" class="tab-content">
                    Texto 3
                </div>
  
  <!-- Abas 4 -->
                <div id="tab-4" data-tab-title="ABA 4" class="tab-content">
                    Texto 4
                </div>
  
  <!-- Abas 5 -->
                <div id="tab-5" data-tab-title="ABA 5" class="tab-content">
                    Texto 5
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Hugo podes mostrar um exemplo de "igual ao do Android" se faz favor

Comment: queria eles preciso com o do materialize http://materializecss.com/tabs.html, quando a tela e pequena ele gera uma barra de rolagem, na vertical